# Parse URL with DOMXPath

Tags: php, domxpath

i can't figure out how to get a url with DOMXPath.

```html
 <div class="row">
<div class='col-md-12'>
<div class="RAElencoCanali RAEC02 elem_1 row_odd RAEC1">
<p class="RACalDate">
<span class="data">
<span class="day">06</span>
<span class="mouth">mar</span>
</span></p> 
    <h2><a title="Seminario: Confindustria Ancona" href="https://www.univpm.it/Confindustria_MarcheNord_seminario_on_line_-_marzo_2021">
    <span>Seminario: Confindustria Ancona</span></a></h2>   
    <p class="RADate">
18 marzo 2021</p>
    <div class="RAFloatClear RARow1px">&nbsp;</div>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

with the php code I would like to take the link but I can't

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$titolo1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2')->Item(3); 
$tagsTitolo = $xpath->query("*/a[@title='".$titolo1->nodeValue."']");
```

Thanks for your cooperation

Comment: there is no third element, and title `$titolo1->nodeValue` will contain a bunch of whitespace then not match, see https://3v4l.org/NLnf9

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//h2/a/@href');
if($elements->length > 0) {
    echo $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```